# Adapter implementation with HashMap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view

`ListView`s ask `Adapter`s for `View`s before they can be seen on screen. The default implementation of an `Adapter` actually inflates your views when the `ListView` asks for them.

When using an `Object extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject>`, we could actually store all the views in a `HashMap<MyObject, SoftReference<View>>` and override `ArrayAdapter.getView` so we can inflate our `Views` only once, but if the `GarbageCollector` passes and makes our `Views` `null` (or my `SoftReferences` are made `null` for any strange reason) we inflate them again.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
        final ViewGroup parent)
{
    final MyObject mo = getItem(position);
    if (hashMap.get(mo) == null || hashMap.get(mo).get() == null)
    {
        final MyCustomView mcv = new MyCustomView(getContext());
        hashMap.put(mo, new SoftReference<MyObject>(mcv));
    } 
    return hashMap.get(mo).get();
}
```

I've tried it and it works fine and nice. Is this implementation disencouraged in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we could actually store all the views

You should use ViewHolder pattern. It allows you not to create **all** the views, but only those you need to display on the screen at the moment.

Comment: Actually, with the ViewHolders you only need to inflate views once, because it's a static class. Calling `findViewById()` is very demanding.

Comment: This approach creates the views as the ListView demands them, but creates them only once. Isn't it the same?

Comment: @santirivera92 The thing is to inflate views only once. Then you should reuse views. If only 6 listview items can be shown on the screen at a time, you don't need 100 listview items. You only need 6.

Comment: Where are those views that are not being shown but have been inflated stored?

Comment: The point is, you don't have views which are not used. You have the exact number of views: if screen can show only 6 views in list at a time, you have 6 views. And then you REUSE them. You separate the representation and data, so you store data in List or Set(which is a field of your Adapter object).